# Java compile error calling .toArray(1) on an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Java compile time error: "cannot find symbol"

```
ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<String>();
List l=new ArrayList(al);
l.add("renu");
String [] as=new String[1];
as=l.toArray(1);
for (int i=0;i<1;i++) {
  System.out.println(as[i]);
}
```

I've imported `List` interface and `ArrayList` class. And `toArrayList` seems to perfectly work with `ArrayList` but not with `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes, in particular this will cause a compilation error: `l.toArray(1)`. To fix them, let's make sure that you're importing the right classes and interfaces:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Now, let's try with this code:

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add("renu");
String[] as = new String[1];
as = al.toArray(as); // this is how we convert a List into an array
for (int i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(as[i]);
}
```

As a side note, you don't really have to convert a `List` to an array to iterate over it, the following code is equivalent and a much better alternative:

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add("renu");
for (String s : al) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you include the error message? My guess is you're having an issue with this line:

```
as = l.toArray( 1 );
```

It looks like it'd throw a casting error, so try something like

```
String[] as;
as = (String[]) l.toArray();
```

Comment: your right sir...the above code yo wrote compiles but it produces an exception ClassCastException....